# How do I use parameters and return in C#?

Tags: c#, types, parameters, return

For the life of me, every tutorial I look through, every video I've seen, every book I've read, I just can not understand how these things work exactly.

I see passing Values by Value, Value by Reference, Reference by Value, Reference by Reference. Can someone help me understand these with the most basic examples?

Same question in regards to return types. How do they work?

Answer (score 3):

The best resource you will find on this is [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet.  It gives a very clear explanation.  If after reading that you still have questions, you should try to ask them more specifically so it is easier to help you.

Comment: People keep telling me to ask more specifically but I don't get how "show me how to use this stuff in the most basic way" isn't specific >_>

Comment: @Bill: The problem is that your question is a bit like asking "How do I use variables in algebra?" -- it's a simple question, but it has a not-very-simple answer that this type of web site isn't very good for.

Answer (score 0):

Let's back up a bit and start with variables.

Variables always contain some specific information.  For value types, the information contained is the entire value directly.  For reference types, the information contained is only a reference to some other memory location where the real value lives.

In .Net, you can pretend that variables are only really passed to or returned from functions in one way: by value.  Forget passing by reference for now — it will just confuse things.  When you pass a variable by value, the entire information *directly held* by the variable is *copied* to the function.  The trick is understanding what this means for reference types, and that is simply that a copy of the reference is taken.

I can demonstrate with a simple code sample:

```
void Test(int x, dynamic y)
{
    x = 3; 
    y.a = "four";
    y.b = "five";
    y = new {a = "six", b = "seven"}; // this will have no effect outside the function
}

int x = 2; // value type
var y = new {a = "one", b="two"}; //reference type

// both x and y are passed by value, but y is a reference type so the reference itself is copied
Test(x, y);

Console.WriteLine(x);  //writes 2, because the test function is working with a copy
Console.WriteLine(y.a); //writes four
Console.WriteLine(y.b); //writes five
```

In the case of reference types, you can force a true "pass by reference", but **you should never do this** unless you *really* know what's going on.  That would look something like this:

```
void Test(ref dynamic y)
{
   y = new {a = "three", b="four"};
}

var y = new {a = "one", b="two"};
Test(y);

Console.WriteLine(y.a); //prints one
Console.WriteLine(y.b); //prints two
```

The output is still "one" and "two" because the function replaced the reference for the local variable.  The code that called the function still has the reference to the original memory location, and so outputs the original value.

Comment: You _can_ pretend that everything is passed by value, but you'd then have to ignore some very useful stuff.

Comment: Yes. I suppose there was an implied "for now" that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you only see passing by value , or passing by reference. Not anything else.
Now to understand this concept, imagine you have a set of digital boxes  marked 1,2,3, 4 etc. These boxes contain some data.
Then imagine you have a list of paper that states the same thing, i.e an index with 1,2,3,4.

Now you want to pass one of the contents(data) of the boxes to your friend.
You can do it in one of these two ways.

1. Passing by Value
   Your friend checks your box, and copies it in his box/harddrive whatever. Assume your friend needs to change this data. If he does so, your original box is not affected because he changes the data that is in his box.
2. Passing by Reference
   You just give the address of the box to your friend, and your friend will USE YOUR BOX instead of copying it. If he modifies the data, it will be from your box, your original data will be changed.

Before you understand return types, you have to understand data types. Begin there.

Comment: I get that references change the original, and values use a copy. I think my issue is just, I'm just not sure how to use them/when to use them.

Comment: Always use passing by value. Save passing by reference after you are much better at programming. Learn about data types, some programming and then functions.  You'll have to start from the basics.

Comment: Agree with Mr Zen, I don't know of even one method at this point in time in the .net framework that even uses pass by reference.  In most cases what you pass into a method gives you back something totally unrelated.  Adding pass by reference may make it a little more difficult to debug if something goes wrong.  Almost feels like adding pass by reference removes the encapsulation of that method